# Customize ScrewTurn Wiki to store and reuse C# source code

Tags: screwturn

I am working on a research project.I need to customize ScrewTurn Wiki to store C# source code.It can reuse the code by linking.
e.g. I have a add function and add function will be stored as a wiki page.If someone would like to add 2 integer then instead of writing their own ,they can simply reuse the add function by linking the page. [url]add/url.

The user can write code by reusing the existing function like shown above and be able to download a complete source code and preview the source code.

My question is that I am very new to ScrewTurn Wiki, I need some suggestions to where do I start?What is the best way of customizing it given I only have 2 months.
Any suggestions are much appropriated.